# Relative URL slash when using base tag

Tags: html, jsp

I'm trying to learn more about the way paths are interpreted with a JSP.

When using an HTML base tag in combination with a relative URL, is it pretty standard to end the base href with a slash?

The reason I am asking is because I often need to express things in terms of the context root within a JSP (for a form action for example), so that the form is routed to the appropriate servlet as I've mapped it in web.xml.

Most of the time I would just use `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` every time, until I learned about the base tag.

However, I'm guessing that since in a JSP the slash is interpreted by the server as the root of the web application, I can't have my base be, for example:

```
<base href="/foo"/>
```

and then in the form have:

```
<form action="/extension">
...
</form>
```

Since this would cause the form to be submitted to `mydomain.com/extension` instead of `mydomain.com/foo/extension`. Am I understanding this correctly, that since slash has special meaning, you generally need to end the base HREF with a backslash to get the desired effect?

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Not really.

Browsers do not simply concatenate your base `href` attributes and relative URLs.
Instead, `<base>` tag sets the *Document base URL* which is then used to dynamically generate a new path.

You can see an interesting example in the WHATWG HTML specification:

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/news/index.html">
<p>Visit the <a href="archives.html">archives</a>.</p>
```

Note that the `href` attribute even ends with a filename.

This means that if you do not put a trailing slash to your base `href` attribute, `foo` will be treated as the last, volatile part of the path and will essentially be removed. By way of example:

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/news/index.html" />
<img src="ball.png" /> <!-- GET http://www.example.com/news/ball.png -->
```

---

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/news/" />
<img src="ball.png" /> <!-- GET http://www.example.com/news/ball.png -->
```

---

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/news" />
<img src="ball.png" /> <!-- GET http://www.example.com/ball.png -->
```

---

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/" />
<img src="ball.png" /> <!-- GET http://www.example.com/ball.png -->
```

---

```
<!-- If served from http://www.example.com: -->
<base href="/" />
<img src="ball.png" /> <!-- GET http://www.example.com/ball.png  -->
```

Comment: but wouldn't the example take you to http://www.example.com/news/index.html/archives.html?

Comment: That is the point, it wouldn't. It will take you to `example.com/news/archives.html`.

Comment: I see. So what would be the advantage or communication of intent for using: <base href="http://www.example.com/news/index.html"> instead of <base href="http://www.example.com/news"> Seems like the latter is more clear

Comment: Or were you just using that as an example, and using index.html at the end isn't something you would normally see?

Comment: That was just an example, I wouldn't usually put a file there at the end. But do note that your fixed version `example.com/news` will now drop `news`, as you did not add a trailing slash. You'd want to use `example.com/news/`.

Comment: @Denis Just to let you know that the links in your answer no longer work.