# All my links are broken when changing publish URL

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

Moving from http://basedomain
to
http://basedomain/anotherlevel/

Everything breaks because it's still looking in http://basedomain. I tried changing `<base href="/" />` to `<base href="/anotherlevel" />` and `<base href="http://basedomain/anotherlevel" />` but it had no effect. I'm still getting this:
[image]

I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: This doesn't look like Angular, it looks like AngularJS. What version are you using?

Comment: Angular 2 - version 4.0.3

Comment: I stand corrected! So, you're the one still using systemjs with Angular, huh? :D

Comment: Ha ha! I put off figuring out Webpack and instead put my energy into making a bomb-a** loading animation while sysstemjs chunks away at my 200+ js files =D I wish I was kidding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `<base href="/anotherlevel" />` to `<base href="/anotherlevel/" />`.

See [Relative URL slash when using base tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042822/relative-url-slash-when-using-base-tag).

The `href` attribute on the `base` tag requires a trailing slash. Without a trailing slash, the browser will treat the trailing path element as if it were a file rather than a directory. This means that requests will still be made in the root URI context.

Comment: @AndrewBenjamin: Also if your SPA is embedded in a razor page/view, you can use `<base href="~/" />`. It will use the app relative path