# All of my routes include a hashtag after the host before the resource, host.com/#/resource, any idea what I might have done to cause this?

Tags: react-admin

Some examples of how my admin and resources are configured:

```
<Admin
    dashboard={Dashboard}
    dataProvider={dataProvider}
    appLayout={MainLayout}
    title="Removed So I Don't Get Fired"
  >
    <Resource name="apples" list={ApplesList} />
    <Resource name="pears" list={PearsList} show={PearShow} />
    <Resource name="peaches" list={PeachesList} create={PeachesCreate} edit={PeachesEdit}/>
  </Admin>
```

the routes that work are all:

```
host.com/#/apples
host.com/#/pears
host.com/#/pears/pearnumber/show
```

etc...

If I try to visit:

```
host.com/apples
host.com/pears
host.com/pears/pearnumber/show
```

The browser is redirected to:

```
host.com/apples#/
host.com/pears#/
host.com/pears/pearnumber/show#/
```

Let me know if you need anything additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/49158969/1941654. I'm not a React expert, but a crucial component of PushState API routing is that the page must base all routes off of a base URI. If no base URI is specified, then libraries will tend to use the original URI accessed as the base URI.

If you were using the PushState API, then I would suggest that you add `<base href="/" />` to your page `<head>`. This would indicate to your page that all paths are relative to the root of the host. However, it looks like you're just using hash-based routing (though still aliasing all subpaths of `host.com` to your page). Hash-based routing is unable to change the URI path, so you will not be able to get `host.com/apples` to redirect to `host.com/#/apples` with your current setup.

I suggest changing the routing strategy to use the PushState API instead: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/docs/Admin.md#history. This, combined with the `<base>` tag mentioned above, will allow your page to use the root URI as its base URI and fix routing when navigating directly to a route.

The above link suggests using the `history` npm package to create a history configuration (in this case using the `createBrowserHistory` function) and then attach it to the `Admin` node as follows:

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

const history = createHistory({basename: '/'});

const App = () => (
    <Admin history={history}>
        ...
    </Admin>
);
```

Comment: I used the example in the documentation almost exactly and it worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Basically is for history. You can find more information [here](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#history) For the route you try to visit probably are not being recognized and so an # appears after the route. It assumes the route is the host route. Not sure about this last.