# are there scenarios (i.e. browsers) that it matters the trailing backslash in base tag

Tags: html, web, href, meta, radix

Is there any browser that handles differently the values of the `<base>` tag?
Are

```
<base href="http://www.example.com" />
```

and

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/" />
```

the exact same thing in all modern browsers?
(notice the trailing slash in the second example).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative URL slash when using base tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042822/relative-url-slash-when-using-base-tag)

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no difference between a path `/` and a completely empty path.

It only matters when the path is otherwise non-empty. i.e. `http://example.com/foo/` and `http://example.com/foo` are significantly different.