# Angular application Http Request Base Url

Tags: .net, angular, typescript, iis

I have an angular application that I am hosting on a test server on IIS. It is running on a .net core backend. The app is hosted on a virtual directory, e.g www.myTestApp/crm (where www.myTestApp is made up). When building the application I use the following command: ng build --base-href "/CRM" --deploy-url "/CRM/" --prod.

My Http Request from my angular app are firing from [www.mytestapp.com/](http://www.mytestapp.com/) instead of [www.mytestapp.com/crm](http://www.mytestapp.com/crm). How does angular determine the base url in this case even though when building I specified that it should be /crm.

Here is an example of one of my http requests:

```
return this.http
            .get("/api/users/IsOutboundAgent")
            .pipe(map((data: any) => {
                this.isOutboundAgent = data;
                return this.isOutboundAgent;
            }));
```

I know one solution would be to have a global variable before each http request that could be set based on the environment variable, or even using an http intercept. I am just trying to understand why the "crm" part is being omitted. Does angular use the domain name without any paths as a default when they aren't specified?

Comment: You can refer to this link for Deploy Angular application in IIS using base URL: https://medium.com/acute-angular/angular-in-production-deploy-angular-application-in-iis-8-using-base-url-f112f5774198.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that in my http request there was a leading slash added to the request. This caused the url to be relative to the root of the website, which basically ignored the /crm part.

Another thing I noticed was that it is also recommended to add a trailing slash when setting the base tag.

[Relative URL slash when using base tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042822/relative-url-slash-when-using-base-tag)

[Relative Url Conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E39072_01/HTMLPages/tpc/acbd86fa-095f-4882-bf61-df9d876b4c17/index.html#:%7E:text=A%20relative%20URL%20that%20begins,name%20of%20the%20base%20URL.&text=A%20relative%20URL%20that%20begins%20with%20%2F%2F%20(2%20slashes)%20always,everything%20from%20the%20hostname%20onward.&text=An%20Address%20field%20that%20contains,points%20to%20the%20base%20URL.)